# Shortcut to make case/switch return a value

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I'm pretty sure I saw someone do a shortcut technique like the code below (which doesn't work)

```
return case guess
  when guess > @answer then :high
  when guess < @answer then :low
  else :correct
end
```

Does anyone know the trick I'm referring to?

Comment: Just for fun, you could also say `{ -1 => :low, 0 => :correct, 1 => :high }[guess <=> @answer]`.

Comment: That looks like madness. I'll try it soon. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is, I don't recommend you do it in real life, that's why I didn't include it in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
return case
  when guess > @answer ; :high
  when guess < @answer ; :low
  else ; :correct
  end
```

Comment: indeed it does. Wasn't exactly the trick I saw before, but it's just as nice! Thanks.

Comment: You need not to put a semicolon after else. Just a nitpick.

Comment: The op only needed to remove the word guess from 'case guess'. The case form demonstrated in this answer, a list of boolean conditions, would normally have 'then' instead of ';'.  see mu's answer.

Answer (score 17):

A `case` statement does return a value, you just have to use the right form of it to get the value you're expecting.

There are two forms of `case` in Ruby. The first one looks like this:

```
case expr
when expr1 then ...
when expr2 then ...
else ...
end
```

This will compare `expr` with each `when` expression using `===` (that's a triple BTW) and it will execute the first `then` where `===` gives a true value. For example:

```
case obj
when Array then do_array_things_to(obj)
when Hash  then do_hash_things_to(obj)
else raise 'nonsense!'
end
```

is the same as:

```
if(Array === obj)
  do_array_things_to(obj)
elsif(Hash === obj)
  do_hash_things_to(obj)
else
  raise 'nonsense!'
end
```

The other form of `case` is just a bunch of boolean conditions:

```
case
when expr1 then ...
when expr2 then ...
else ...
end
```

For example:

```
case
when guess > @answer then :high
when guess < @answer then :low
else :correct
end
```

is the same as:

```
if(guess > @answer)
  :high
elsif(guess < @answer)
  :low
else
  :correct
end
```

You're using the first form when you think you're using the second form so you end up doing strange (but syntactically valid) things like:

```
(guess > @answer) === guess
(guess < @answer) === guess
```

In either case, `case` is an expression and returns whatever the matched branch returns.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the `guess` from the `case`, because it's not valid ruby syntax.

For example:

```
def test value
  case 
  when value > 3
    :more_than_3
  when value < 0
    :negative
  else
    :other
  end
end
```

Then

```
test 2   #=> :other 
test 22  #=> :more_than_3 
test -2  #=> :negative
```

The `return` is implicit.

**Edit:** you can use `then` if you like too, the same example would look like this:

```
def test value
  case 
    when value > 3 then :more_than_3
    when value < 0 then :negative
    else :other
  end
end
```

Comment: Um, `case x when y ...` is perfectly valid in Ruby. The problem is that there are two forms of `case` and the OP is confused about which one they're using.

Comment: Yes, I meant that you can't use it like `case x when x > 2`, I'm guilty of not giving a proper explanation

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on @mu's first comment on the question (an approach that looks fine to me), you could of course also write that as:

```
return case (guess <=> @answer)
       when -1 then :low
       when  0 then :correct
       when  1 then :high
       end
```

or

```
       ...
       else
         :high
       end
```