# Ruby Conditionals/Case Expression

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to code and I have a quick question on Ruby conditionals, specifically Case Expressions. I have a method in which I want to return a string "odd" if the string length is odd and "even" if the string length is even.

Simple stuff I know and I can get the results using a if/else conditional, however the case expression just returns 'nil'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def odd_or_even(string)
  case string
  when string.length.even? then "even"
  when string.length.odd? then "odd"
  end
end

odd_or_even("Ruby") # Wanting to return even rather than nil
odd_or_even("Rails") # Wanting to return odd rather than nil
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut to make case/switch return a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671307/shortcut-to-make-case-switch-return-a-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've written your `case` statement wrong. It takes two forms, which is unusual compared to other languages. The first form takes an argument, and that argument is compared to all possible cases. The second form is without argument and each case is evaluated independently.

The most minimal fix is this:

```
def odd_or_even(string)
  case
  when string.length.even? then "even"
  when string.length.odd? then "odd"
  end
end
```

This was because to Ruby your code looked like this when calling with the argument "Ruby":

```
def odd_or_even(string)
  case string
  when true then "even"
  when false then "odd"
  end
end
```

Your `string` value does not match `true` or `false` so you get `nil` from a non-matching situation.

You can clean up your code considerably. Consider: Can something be not even *and* not odd? Not really:

```
def odd_or_even(string)
  string.length.even? ? 'even' : 'odd'
end
```

Comment: Thank you kindly @tadman. I very much appreciate your time and feedback.

Comment: HeresJohnny5, your code would have worked had you substituted `case string.length.even?` for `case string` above. btw, are there really at least five HeresJohnny's on SO?

Comment: That's what happens when [you let a robot pick its own name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Circuit_\(1986_film\)). I like the mashup between Carson, (King?), and *Short Circuit*.

Answer (score 0):

```
case something
  when condition1
    expression1
  when condition2
    expression2
  else
    default_expression
end
```

is equivalent to

```
if condition1 === something
  expression1
elsif condition2 === something
  expression2
else
  default_expression
end
```

Note that `case-when` internally uses `===`, an operator (method) which can be overridden.