# How does a ruby case statement with multiple conditions work

Tags: ruby

My Code:

```
def double_mails?(mail)

  if @mails_hash.include?(mail) && @mails_hash[mail] > 0
      p "true"
      return true
  elsif @mails_hash.include?(mail) && @mails_hash[mail] == 0
      @mails_hash[mail] =+ 1
      p "false double"
      return false
  else
      p "false else"
      return false
  end
end
```

My Question:

When I try to make a case statement like this out of the above code  the programm  logic doesn't work anymore:

```
def double_mails?(mail)
  case mail
    when @mails_hash.include?(mail) && @mails_hash[mail] > 0
      p "true"
      return true
    when @mails_hash.include?(mail) && @mails_hash[mail] == 0
      @mails_hash[mail] =+ 1
      p "false double"
      return false
    else
      p "false else"
      return false
  end
end
```

It alway jumps into the else block no matter which value I pass in. The if..else works fine.
Why doesn't it work and how do I fix the syntax to make it work as a case statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need for `return` in either case it is implicit in Ruby. Also, what "doesn't work"? What happens? Also this might help understand what's going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671307/shortcut-to-make-case-switch-return-a-value

Comment: It is not a duplicate

Comment: Of course it is. If you read the highest voted answer in that question you would understand why your code wasn't working as expected. You're using the `case expression` form and expecting it to behave as the simpler `case` form. It also answers your other question of how to fix it, so it is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the exact substitute of `if`-`elsif` functionality, you should use *empty* `case` condition:

```
case
when @mails_hash.include?(mail) && @mails_hash[mail] > 0
  p "true"
  true
when @mails_hash.include?(mail) && @mails_hash[mail] == 0
  @mails_hash[mail] =+ 1
  p "false double"
  false
else
  p "false else"
  false
end
```

When you put an argument in call to `case`, it’s used to compare against `when` clauses using threeequals aka case-equal:

```
case mail
when MailClass then ...
end
```

The code above actually calls `MailClass.===(mail)`.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Just what I was searching for.