# Switch statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an email address and I would like to check if it is in different model, in which case, return the id in that model.
I wrote the following:

```
 def find_contact(email)
    case email
    when !User.find_by(email: email).nil?
      return User.find_by(email: email).id
    when !Viewer.find_by(email: email).nil?
      return Viewer.find_by(email: email).id
    else
      return "No information"
    end
  end
```

When i try with any email, it returns `No Information` even for the current user.
What am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcut to make case/switch return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671307/shortcut-to-make-case-switch-return-a-value)

Comment: Besides the duplicate, `User.where(email: email).nil?` will never be true, you'd want `User.find_by(email: email).nil?` or `User.where(email: email).exists?`.

Comment: You're also checking whether `email` *matches* the condition of whether or not a field is present. Basically, you'll end up checking whether `true === email` or `false === email` (Note that in Ruby, `===` is the case match operator), which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Hi, sorry there was an error in my code and I have corrected it now. What I am looking to do, if theer is a User with that email, return the id of the use, otherwise if there is a Viewer with that email, return his id, else return no information.

Comment: Btw. your code can be simplified to just `User.find_by(email: email)&.id || Viewer.find_by(email: email)&.id || "No information"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this answer is not about `case`, but it seems that `case` is not needed here

And I suspect that `id` as such is also irrelevant. They can be repeated (or not repeated) in different tables

The `"No information"` string also looks quite strange

Therefore, I would suggest returning a record corresponding to the email. If no such record is found, `nil` will be returned. And somewhere outside process this `nil`

```
def find_contact(email)
  User.find_by(email: email) || Viewer.find_by(email: email)
end
```

Comment: Wow, one line! thank you very much, i overcomplicated things.